# Sum values from two columns in View MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I would like to sum values I get from two columns, these values are added from the data collected in View page based on customers so adding it in a controller from database is not an option as far as I know, I could be wrong
Any help would be appreciated.

I can get sum of two columns individually but can't get sum of two columns.

```
<table class="table">
    <tr>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.PkgBasePrice)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Description)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.BasePrice)
        </th>
    </tr>

    @foreach (var item in Model.Where(ModelItem => 
ModelItem.CustomerId.Equals(Session["CustomerId"])))
    {
    <tr>

        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.PkgBasePrice)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Description)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.BasePrice)
        </td>

    </tr>
    }

</table>
<h2>
    Package Total: $@Model.Where(c => 
c.CustomerId.Equals(Session["CustomerId"])).Sum(b => b.PkgBasePrice)

</h2>
<h2>
    Product Total: $@Model.Where(c => 
c.CustomerId.Equals(Session["CustomerId"])).Sum(b => b.BasePrice)

</h2>
```

I would like to get sum of PkgBasePrice and BasePrice in one amount

Comment: I think you're overcomplicating this. if you can get the sum of 2 separate things and your goal is to get the sum of those 2 separate sums, then just add them together. `Model.Single(ModelItem => 
ModelItem.CustomerId.Equals(Session["CustomerId"])).Sum(x => x.PkgBasePrice) + Model.Single(ModelItem => 
ModelItem.CustomerId.Equals(Session["CustomerId"])).Sum(x => x.BasePrice)` ?

Comment: you need to wrap it like so `@(Model..... + Model....)` see my answer

Comment: itd help if you posted your model class. check the updated answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you already have the two individual sums you want to combine, you can add the two sums you have together as follows:

```
@(@Model.Where(c => c.CustomerId.Equals(Session["CustomerId"])).Sum(b => b.PkgBasePrice) + 
    @Model.Where(c => c.CustomerId.Equals(Session["CustomerId"])).Sum(b => b.BasePrice))
```